# Fetching data in background

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am making an app, that fetches a lot of data when logging in. I would like to fetch this data from the web service in the background.
With "background" I mean something like the App.cs or something. The data is loaded, while the user browses it's way through my app pages.

My app now loads all the data on the login page, and then shows the main page. I would like the app to load the data, when I am on the main page, without the user having to wait.

Is such thing possible?

Thanks in advance

Matthew

Comment: enjoy your next 15 minutes http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-19-Understanding-async-and-Awaitable-Tasks

Comment: I know wat async and awaitable means. But I already tried something like it. When I call my async operation to the service, it seems like my app is freezing and waiting for the data to arrive.
I want to be able to navigate through the pages and when I use async the navigation is waiting for the data ( because I pass it )

Comment: And why you bother anymore? I don't understand

Comment: If you perform an async operation it's still handled on the UI thread! You need to wrap it in Task.Run(() => ... ) to get it to spin off a background thread

Comment: But do read up on the correct and incorrect usage of it here: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html and http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

Answer (score 0):

Schedule the data download as a [ResourceIntensiveTask Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.scheduler.resourceintensivetask(v=vs.105).aspx). As the [Background agents for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx) This is the best way to manage apps that have large data downloads that are not continually needed for instant use, like a navigation app.

It will download the data when the phone is not in other use and has good charge, and be ready for the when the user wants to use the app.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this as soon as I can !